# VueJS 2 - Bootstrap modal - remove default classes

Tags: html, vue.js, sass, vuejs2

I would like to remove the default classes on the bootstraps modal footer which override my classes.

Here is the code from my footer :

```html
<template #modal-footer="{hide}">
  <section class="footer">
    <b-button class="button button-white" @click="cancel(hide)">
      Cancel
    </b-button>
    <b-button class="button button-blue" @click="confirm(hide)">
      Create Template
    </b-button>
  </section>
</template>
```

At render it goes here :

```
<section class="footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn button button-white btn-secondary">
        Cancel
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn button button-blue btn-secondary">
        Create Template
    </button>
</section>
```

I want to remove the default classes **btn** and **btn-secondary**

I tried to add `variant="none"` or even add `!important` (made my cry), and nothing works...